# Информирует ли как-то StackOverflow Участника, что его тот или иной Вопрос/Ответ был удален?

Tags: поддержка, удаление-вопросов, удаление-ответов

Информирует ли как-то StackOverflow Участника, что его тот или иной Вопрос/Ответ был удален по каким-либо причинам? Имеются ввиду Вопросы/Ответы канувшие в такое прошлое, что их удаление кем-либо за что-либо практически незаметно, но при этом не удаленные сразу при публикации.

Было бы неплохо просто быть проинформированным о причинах. Зная причины можно сделать выводы. Отслеживать самостоятельно как-то хлопотно.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, нет. Но имея 10К репутации, все свои удалённые сообщения можно найти по `deleted:true`. У каждого автоматически удалённого вопроса показывается причина удаления. Да и вообще, все они известны.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Буду знать. Спасибо

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Автоматических уведомлении при удалении собственных вопросов или ответов не предусмотрено. Однако, как уже упомянуто в комментариях, можно через поиск [найти свои удалённые сообщения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=deleted%3A1), если ваша репутация достигла 10К, т.е. получена привилегия ["Инструменты модератора"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).

> [image: deleted]

Если репутация ещё не достигла 10К, то свежие удалённые вопросы и ответы можно найти в профиле на соответствующих вкладках [вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=questions) и [ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=answers) в самом низу списка:

> [image: недавно удалённые]